# returning value to a function in jquery dialog

Tags: jquery, dialog

I am using jquery dialog box jquery. I have some condition in function. I have prepaid a demo similar like actual code it is working on local but however not working in the fiddle. What i want is when user click 'open box' then based on user selection we alter accordingly. But the problem is when user is clicking 'open box' is altering massage. It is not waiting till the user choose his selection. I want to do with function wait till user select his option then alert. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/DNRLS/1/)

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<a href="javascript:checkvisible(0)">open box</a>

<div id="dialog" >
<p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
 var val= $('#dialog').dialog({autoOpen: false,  buttons: {
"OK": function () {
$(this).dialog("close");
return true;
},
"cancel": function () {
$(this).dialog("close");
return false;
}
}});

function openTo(Id_, width_) {  
var divId = $('#' + Id_);
divId.dialog('option', 'width', parseInt(width_));
divId.dialog('option', 'show', 'clip');
divId.dialog('option', 'hide', 'clip');
divId.dialog('option', 'zIndex', 1000);
divId.dialog('open');
}

function showbox (){
openTo('dialog',200)
}

function checkvisible(notes){
if(notes){
// do something 
}

else {
var procees= showbox();
if(procees){
alert('ok')
}
else {
alert('cancelled')
}
}
}
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/DNRLS/1/

Comment: @Barmar jquery ui was included as external resources... problem was with some function scopings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dialog widget work asynchronously, so you will not get any value returned from it. The solution is to use custom event handlers and callbacks

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var val = $('#dialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        buttons: {
            "OK": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                $(this).trigger('confirm');
            }, "cancel": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                $(this).trigger('cancel');
            }
        }
    });
})


function openTo(Id_, width_, okCallback, cancelCallback) {
    var divId = $('#' + Id_);
    divId.dialog('option', 'width', parseInt(width_));
    divId.dialog('option', 'show', 'clip');
    divId.dialog('option', 'hide', 'clip');
    divId.dialog('option', 'zIndex', 1000);
    divId.dialog('open').off('confirm cancel').on('confirm', okCallback).on('cancel', cancelCallback);
}

function showbox(okCallback, cancelCallback) {
    openTo('dialog', 200, okCallback, cancelCallback)
}

function checkvisible(notes) {
    if (notes) {
        // do something 
    } else {
        showbox(function(){
            alert('ok')
        }, function(){
            alert('cancelled')
        });
    }
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/DNRLS/)

Comment: One more thing. I want to add one more parameter in which i will put massage. showbox(msg, okCallback, cancelCallback). How to set msg with call backfuncton

Comment: @amit http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/DNRLS/3/  also if the answer is working don't forget to mark it as accepted

Comment: why we are using confirm here (msg || 'Confirm') ?

Comment: @amit if not message is passed, it displays `Confirm` as a default message

Comment: is there any alternative for .off. Actually i am using jquery 1.4.2

Comment: Try `divId.dialog('open').unbind('confirm').unbind('cancel').bind('confirm', okCallback).bind('cancel', cancelCallback);`

Comment: One last thing: I have another popup which does not need call back function. Can we pass null to call back method like :function checkme() {
    openTo('dialog', 200, null, null)
}

Comment: but this function does not contains two button it has only one. it is giving error b is undefinded