# Creating a suitable replacement for prompt

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, prompt

My users may use IE7 and I want to avoid using the prompt function. I have working code using prompt but am unsure of a good way to replace it.

My usage requirement is this. User clicks an image button and then has to OK/Cancel a prompt. If OK is pressed, a Reference is requested which is assigned to RemovePalletReference for use in code behind.

```
<asp:imagebutton id="ibRemoveFromPallet" runat="server" ImageUrl="../Images/Icons/removefrompallet.gif" OnClientClick="return ConfirmReroute();"></asp:imagebutton>                   
<asp:HiddenField ID="RemovePalletReference" runat="server" value="" ></asp:HiddenField>
```

You can see above that I first call ConfirmReroute() which is the following js function.

```
    function ConfirmReroute() 
    {
        if (confirm("Confirm Remove Unit From Pallet") == true) 
        {
            var pmt;
            do {
                pmt = prompt("Please Enter a Reference:", "");
            }
            while ( pmt == null || pmt.length < 1);
            document.getElementById('<%= RemovePalletReference.ClientID %>').value = pmt;
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
```

I wish to replace the code where the user has pressed OK to the `confirm`.  I tried with jquery UI modal dialog but could not work it out. I think it may be workable using callbacks but this is a new subject to me and I'm struggling.

Please in answers show some code to help me out. Grateful for any assistance.

Comment: have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18461051/returning-value-to-a-function-in-jquery-dialog#answer-18461239)

Comment: It's useful thanks, please see here: http://pastebin.com/Jvv4NuPF
That's my implementation but I can't test it until I fully integrate it. My concern is where the "finishing" alert is, I can't put a return value there or the buttons click event in code behind will execute before the callbacks are called from the dialog. Not sure what will happen there, e.g in C# the same flow would not compile as not all routes return a value etc.

Answer (score 0):

Ex

```
function confirmDialog(title, message, confirm, reject) {
    var dialog = $('<div />').html(message).dialog({
        appendTo: 'body',
        title: title,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "OK": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                confirm();
            },
                "cancel": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                if ($.isFunction(reject)) {
                    reject();
                }
            }
        },
        close: function (event, ui) {
            $(this).dialog('destroy');
            $(this).remove()
        }
    })
}

function test(notes) {
    confirmDialog('Confirm', 'Confirm Something', function () {
        console.log('ok');
        //what ever you want to do on confirmation has to go here
    }, function () {
        console.log('cancelled')
    });
    //any code added here will get executed before the confirm box is displayed
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/hsUB6/)

Comment: The problem is that at the point at the bottom where execution continues, it seems to imply a return true (due to lack of return false), which allows the button Click eventhandler to fire. The effectiveness of prompt is that it halts the execution where called. Apologies if this is unclear.